# Django other_dict Error

Tags: django

I get the latest 5 messages and events the user has received for the authenticated users with a context processor and this is what i'm using:

```
def notifications(request):
    # only authenticated users will have notifications
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        events = Event.objects.filter(user_to=request.user).order_by('-time_sent')[:5]
        mails = Message.objects.filter(user_to=request.user).order_by('-sent')[:5]
        # return the two resultsets to the template
        return {
            'notification_events': events,
            'notification_mails': mails
        }
```

If the user is logged in it works great, but when I logout I get this error:

```
other_dict must be a mapping (dictionary-like) object
```

At first I thought it was because of the return but it works when the user is authenticated so its possibly an issue with `request.user.is_authenticated()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should default return (fallback dict) when the boolean expression is not satisfied, something like:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    ...
    return {
        'notification_events': events,
        'notification_mails': mails
    }
else:
    #fallback
    return {
        'notification_events': None,
        'notification_mails': None
    }
```

Comment: Alright thank you, it is okay that I just used: *return {}*? I'm using separate templates so there should be no crossover

Comment: It depends! 
If your application always access this dict, so you not must return a empty dict. 
Otherwise, you should return it filled up with default values. In most cases it's better option.

Comment: @CallumBonnyman If my answer was helpful and solve your problem, do not forget to mark it as "accept" answer, ok? ;)